# How do you unwrap a Result on Ok or return from the function on Err?

Tags: rust

I have a function that calls another function which returns a `Result`. I need to check if the `Result` is `Ok` or `Err` and if it is an `Err`, I need to `return` early from my function. This is what I'm doing now:

```
match callable(&mut param) {
    Ok(_v) => (),
    Err(_e) => return,
};
```

Is there a more idiomatic Rust way to do this?

Comment: See also [Unwrap or continue in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49785136/155423)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can create a macro:

```
macro_rules! unwrap_or_return {
    ( $e:expr ) => {
        match $e {
            Ok(x) => x,
            Err(_) => return,
        }
    }
}

fn callable(param: &mut i32) -> Result<i32, ()> {
    Ok(*param)
}

fn main() {
    let mut param = 0;
    let res = unwrap_or_return!(callable(&mut param));

    println!("{:?}", res);
}
```

Note that I wouldn't recommend discarding the errors. Rust's error handling is pretty ergonomic, so I would return the error, even if it is only to log it:

```
fn callable(param: &mut i32) -> Result<i32, ()> {
    Ok(*param)
}

fn run() -> Result<(), ()> {
    let mut param = 0;
    let res = callable(&mut param)?;

    println!("{:?}", res);

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    if let Err(()) = run() {
        println!("Oops, something went wrong!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I also changed your macro to allow the caller to specify whether to `return` or `continue`. Is that idiomatic rust?

Comment: What is the difference between the macro you created here and the `?` operator?

Comment: @Raul The `?` operator can only be used in a function that returns a [`Try`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Try.html) implementor. The OP wants to return from a function that returns unit, and unit does not implement `Try`.

Comment: It is a good idea to add an indirection by adding `run()` that returns a `Result`, for two reasons:  1) inside `run()`, you can use `?` to handle error returns;  2) you can then log/process all error returns in a single place.   IMO,  this is better than creating a macro.

Comment: @user1783732 The main/run thing is outdated: nowadays, the main function can return a result.

Comment: @Boiethios that's okay. Whether the main() can return a result does not matter. My point was that:  when a function `foo` returns () and we still want to use ? to do early returns inside `foo`,  it is a good idea to add a layer of `bar() -> Result()` that includes the actual code to allow ? early returns, then `foo` will call `bar` and log the error.

Comment: Ah, here we go again, macros. Imagine living in parallel world where everything in rust are macros...

Comment: @thebluetropics I'm just like you, I don't like macros, but in this very case, it's just not worth it. I'd go with the bit of boilerplate, or even better, I'd change the function signature to match the intent better.

Answer (score 39):

[Rust 1.65.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1650-2022-11-03) has stabilized [let-else statements](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/3137), which enables you to write:

```rust
let Ok(_v) = callable(&mut param) else { return };
```

Comment: This is my go-to method for `Option<T>` because I know my `else` block is literally dealing with nothing.  But for `Result<O, Error>` I use the OP's method because I want to record the error object in the log before kicking it back.

Answer (score 5):

If both functions return `Result<doesn't matter, same T>` you can just put a `?` at the end of line of call.

```
fn caller() -> Result<Str, i32> {
    let number = job()?; // <-- if job return error this function return/end here 
                         // otherwise the value of Ok will assign to number 
    Ok(format!("the number is {}", number))
}

fn job() -> Result<i32, i32> {
    // do something
    Err(3)
}
```

You can use same pattern for `Option<T>` too.

Comment: It's pretty clear from OPs example code that this isn't the case: `Err(_e) => return,`

Comment: All thought this isn't the answer to the question above. I've remembered that there was SOME syntax like this, but not what exactly, and I couldn't find it until now. So kudos for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use my [unwrap_or](https://lib.rs/crates/unwrap_or) crate to accomplish this.

You can do:

```
unwrap_or_ok!(callable(&mut param), _, return);
```

And if you want the result and to return the error, you can do:

```
let v = unwrap_or_ok!(callable(&mut param), error, return error);
```