# Is there any way of doing unwrap_or_return an Error (any error)

Tags: rust, return, unwrap

Is there any way to simplify the returns in the following example (originally copied from [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/error/result/early_returns.html)):

```
use std::num::ParseIntError;

fn multiply(first_number_str: &str, second_number_str: &str) -> Result<i32, ParseIntError> {
    let first_number = match first_number_str.parse::<i32>() {
        Ok(first_number)  => first_number,
        Err(e) => return Err(e),
    };

    let second_number = match second_number_str.parse::<i32>() {
        Ok(second_number)  => second_number,
        Err(e) => return Err(AnotherError::ParseError("error")),
    };

    Ok(first_number * second_number)
}
```

I mean something like:

```
use std::num::ParseIntError;

fn multiply(first_number_str: &str, second_number_str: &str) -> Result<i32, ParseIntError> {
    let first_number = first_number_str.parse::<i32>()
        .unwrap_or_return(|e| Err(e));

    let second_number = second_number_str.parse::<i32>()
        .unwrap_or_return(|e| Err(AnotherError::ParseError("error"));

    Ok(first_number * second_number)
}
```

Comment: This is similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344951/how-do-you-unwrap-a-result-on-ok-or-return-from-the-function-on-err But not exactly.

Comment: What exactly is `AnotherError::ParseError`? The return type would suggest it has type `ParseIntError`.

Comment: You are right, it's more like pseudocode.
I meant the return can be another error or even Ok(something).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for the [question mark operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/error/result/enter_question_mark.html), possibly combined with [`Result::or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.or) or [`Result::or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.or_else), depending on the specifics of your use-case.

That code example can be rewritten as

```
use std::num::ParseIntError;

pub fn multiply(first_number_str: &str, second_number_str: &str) -> Result<i32, ParseIntError> {
    let first_number = first_number_str.parse::<i32>()?;
    let second_number = second_number_str.parse::<i32>().or_else(|e| Err(e))?;
    // The closure in `or_else` could also return `Ok` or some different error with type `ParseIntError`.
    // let second_number = second_number_str.parse::<i32>().or_else(|_e| Ok(27))?;

    Ok(first_number * second_number)
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6f53a4d582d049fc7fa85fa847b08a4b)

If you know that you're going to return `Ok` in the `or_else`, [`Result::unwrap_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap_or) is more appropriate. Check out the other similar methods on `Result` to see what's offered.

Comment: If you're returning an `Err` from `or_else`, then it might be more clean to just use `map_err` instead.

Comment: `unwrap_or` does not return from the function.
`unwrap_or_return` an Ok as an "early return" on failure is one of the purposes.

Comment: For example, if either `first_number` or `second_number` is not valid, just return Ok(0) as early as possible!

Comment: @Omid The key point is the `?` operator, which *does* return from the function.

Comment: @SCappella not really. Check this out: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ff110726af5329d784bcc0d15eb0f17c

Comment: @Omid Ah, so you want it to return `Ok` in that instance? That wasn't clear from your question. The question mark operator returns if the thing it's applied to is `Err`, not if it's `Ok`. The behavior your want is probably less idiomatic, so I'm not sure there *is* an easy way to do it. I'll experiment with some things, but no guarantees.

Comment: You are right, I'll change the question and approve your answer.
Then will ask another question directly for early returns.