# "mismatched types expected unit type `()` found enum `Option<String>`" Error when trying to read the content of a file with Tauri

Tags: rust, tauri

I was trying to use the file picker of tauri to read the contents of a file in Rust this way.

```
fn open_file() -> Option<String> {
    let dialog_open_file = tauri::api::dialog::FileDialogBuilder::new();
    dialog_open_file.pick_file(|path| {
    match path {
      Some(directory) => {
          let archivo = fs::read_to_string(directory);
          match archivo {
              Ok(content) => { return Some(content); },
              Err(error) => { return None; }
          }
      },
      None => { return None; }
    }
  });
}
```

The problem is that when I try to return Some(content) I get the error "mismatched types expected unit type `()` found enum `Option<String>`"

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:25:43
   |
25 |                   Ok(content) => { return Some(content); },
   |                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found enum
   = note: expected unit type `()`
               found enum `Option<String>`


error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:18:19
   |
18 | fn open_file() -> Option<String> {
   |    ---------      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `Option`, found `()`
   |    |
   |    implicitly returns `()` as its body has no tail or `return` expression
   |
   = note:   expected enum `Option<String>`
           found unit type `()`
```

I have tried many ways but I can't return the Option out of the function "dialog_open_file" to make the function return something.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `tauri` has changed its API in this area. See https://docs.rs/tauri-api/0.7.6/tauri_api/dialog/index.html. Now the functions no longer accept a closure, but instead return a `dialog::Response` struct.

This means your code could be written as something like:

```
// This is tauri's internal error type too.
use anyhow::{Error, bail};

fn open_file_impl() -> Result<String, Error> {
    use tauri::api::dialog::Response;
    let result = tauri::api::dialog::select(None,None)?;
    
    let path = match {
        Response::Okay(s) => s;
        Response::OkayMultiple(s) => bail!("multiple selected"),
        Response::Cancel => bail!("canceled");
    }
    Ok(fs::read_to_string(directory)?)
}

pub fn open_file() -> Option<String> {
   open_file_impl().ok()
}
```

I'd probably introduce a concrete error type with this, rather than relying on `anyhow`... but that does make things longer.

Or you could get rid of the `open_file_impl` altogether...

```
fn open_file_impl() -> Option<String> {
    use tauri::api::dialog::Response;

    let result = tauri::api::dialog::select(None,None).ok()?;
    if let Response::Okay(path) = result {
        fs::read_to_string(directory).ok()
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Edit

This post does not work for the OP question, because tauri's API requires the closure to be `'static`, and thus rules out the possibility (except with dirty `unsafe` hacks) to retrieve the content of the file in a way similar to what was asked.

Also, tauri's API has been changed in more recent versions. If you are only interested in a solution that specifically works with tauri, please see @Michael Anderson's answer.

---

As you can see, there are two errors, which are opposite, in some way: one error tells you that Rust expected `()`, but found `Option<String>`, and the other one that it expected `Option<String>`, but found `()`. This should prompt you to check if you are passing you `Option<String>` at the right place and, in fact, you're not.

A closure *is* a function (not quite the same as other functions you define with `fn`, but still a function), so when you call `return` in it, you're actually returning inside the closure. So, the error just comes from the fact that `pick_file` expected a function that returns `()`, whereas you provided one that returns `Option<String>`, and conversely the outer function is (implicitly) returning `()`.

You may ask: is there a way to return from inside the closure, but for the return statement to apply to the outside function, and the answer is [no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344951/how-do-you-unwrap-a-result-on-ok-or-return-from-the-function-on-err), so one way would be to create a variable outside and mutate it from inside the closure:

```rust
fn open_file() -> Option<String> {
    let dialog_open_file = tauri::api::dialog::FileDialogBuilder::new();
    let mut result = None;
    dialog_open_file.pick_file(|path| {
        if let Some(directory) = path {
            let archivo = fs::read_to_string(directory);
            if let Ok(content) = archivo {
                result = Some(content);
            }
        }
    });
    result
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this throws an error because "result" is borrowed inside the closure and then is used at the end?

Comment: Nope (I tried it before posting). The simple explanation is that the borrow is only needed for as long as the call to `pick_file` lasts; and that call must end *before* the function returns

Comment: Well I comment this because, first, the original code throws me a syntax error with the expreison Ok(content) => result ... saying "expected expression but found =>"

So I changed your code to just "result = Some(content);" but it does throws me an error saying that the "closure may outlive the function, but it borrows 'result'"

And

"cannot move out of `result` because it is borrowed"

Comment: Weird, maybe I did a typo in copy-pasting the code from the playground. I'm going to check it out and edit with a working version :/

Comment: Oh well, yeah, of course, when I changed the `match` to an `if let`, I forgot to remove the `=>` :P. Besides that, when I try it, it works fine, no lifetime errors. Maybe it's due to the tauri`s pick_file signature? I have used a simplified one in my test.

Comment: I have checked `pick_file`'s signature and, indeed, they require the closure to be `'static`, which rules out getting some information out of it.

Comment: I understand, thanks for your time anyways

Answer (score -1):

If you format your code, you would find out that you are missing the return statement in the outer space.

```rust
fn open_file() -> Option<String> {
    let dialog_open_file = tauri::api::dialog::FileDialogBuilder::new();
    let mut result = None;
    dialog_open_file.pick_file(|path| match path {
        Some(directory) => {
            let archivo = fs::read_to_string(directory);
            match archivo {
                Ok(content) => result = Some(content),
                Err(error) => result = None,
            }
        }
    });
    result
}
```

Comment: This function will always return `None`. Not sure that this is what the OP meant.

Comment: Also, this will still not compile...

Comment: yes, it will always return None, I have fixed this.