# Is there any way to return from a function from inside a closure?

Tags: rust, return, closures

I have the following simplified code:

```
fn f() -> i32 {
    let a = some_result.unwrap_or_else(|_| {
        return 1; // want to return this value from f <-------------
    });
}
```

I want to return the value `1` from the whole function `f` in this specific error case but I can't figure out how to do it from within a closure.

If I instead use a `match` expression, it works fine as follows:

```
fn f() -> i32 {
    let a = match some_result {
        Ok(result) => result,
        Err(_)     => { return 1; },
    };
}
```

However, this makes the code verbose since I have the trivial `Ok` match arm.

Comment: You could just go, `.unwrap_or(1)`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, there is not.

A closure is a method (a kind of function) under the hood. You are asking for the ability to exit a parent function from an arbitrarily deeply nested function call. Such non-local flow control has generally proven to be extremely bad for programmer sanity and program maintenance.

---

To solve your problem:

- [How do you unwrap a Result on Ok or return from the function on Err?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51344951/155423)

Comment: That makes sense. I was just hopeful that there was something similar to Kotlin's `return@` in the case of a closure parameter

Answer (score 2):

I would like to show you a trick.

If you make a mutable valuable for the exception case, you can set the value in the closure. And then, you could make the function returning specific value.

```
fn f() -> i32 {
    let mut invalid: bool = false; // + It is for the exception case

    let a = some_result.unwrap_or_else(|_| {
        // return 1; // want to return this value from f <-------------
        invalid = true; // + If the case is exceptional,
    });

    if invalid { // + If the value is marked, return specific value
        return 1;
    }
    ...
}
```

Because a closure is a method, there is no way exactly.
I would like to comment that it is just a trick.