# Early exit when matching result type

Tags: rust

I have a method with a parameter of type `Result`. I like chaining a lot, so I use `and_then` on the parameter. At some point, I want to return the whole method from inside the `and_then` conditionally (so there is a chance another `and_then` method can be called):

```
enum Good {
    Ok,
    Good,
    VeryGood,
}
enum Pizza {
    Tomato,
    Pineapple,
}
enum Burger {
    Cow,
}

enum Food {
    Pizza(Pizza),
    Burger(Burger),
}

fn main() {}

fn s(r: Result<Good, ()>) -> Result<Food, ()> {
    r.and_then(|o| {
        match o {
            // Should be called in the next and_then block
            Good::Ok => Ok(Pizza::Tomato),
            // Should be called in the next and_then block
            Good::Good => Ok(Pizza::Pineapple),
            Good::VeryGood => {
                // I am done. Don't call the next and_then block, but rather return the whole value to the caller.
                return Ok(Food::Burger(Burger::Cow));
            }
        }
    })
    .and_then(|p: Pizza| {
        // At this point, the closure input value should be pizza, because that's the only returned value
        Ok(Food::Pizza(p))
    })
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8c3751e11b8debb322081758026dc962)

I get all kinds of compiler errors:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:30:27
   |
30 |                 return Ok(Food::Burger(Burger::Cow));
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `Pizza`, found enum `Food`
   |
   = note: expected type `Pizza`
              found type `Food`
```

I hope there is a way to make it compile. I could break down the method and get rid of the `and_then`, but maybe there is a way with `and_then`.

In my real code, I have more `and_then`'s which maps types to other types, error mapping etc, so this is a simplified reproduction path of the problem I am facing.

This is copy-pasted code from my codebase, showing the multiple `and_then`. I am mapping errors from external libraries into my own error type, so errors can be returned automatically if there are any. I want to keep changing the type that I got from the `and_then` so I can eventually get type `User` (although it is currently not working). An option is to not chain the blocks and create separate values, but I was hoping I could directly return values to the caller inside a closure.

```
db_session
    .query_with_values(query, values)
    .map_err(|e| {
        error!("{:?}", e);
        TechnicalServerError::SERVER_RETRY
    })
    .and_then(|f| {
        f.get_body().map_err(|e| {
            error!("{:?}", e);
            TechnicalServerError::SERVER_RETRY
        })
    })
    .and_then(|b| b.into_rows().ok_or(TechnicalServerError::SERVER_RETRY))
    .and_then(|mut c| {
        if let Some(row) = c.pop() {
            User::try_from_row(row).map_err(|e| {
                error!("{:?}", e);
                TechnicalServerError::SERVER_INVALID
            })
        } else {
            return Ok(Login::Other(LoginResult::UNKNOWN_USER));
        }
    })
    .and_then(|u| {
        // 'u' should be of type 'user' at this point
        // some user code here...
    })
```

Comment: The code you posted was not compiling. Could you edit it to show us the workflow better? Also, why are you returning early? Is there a specific reason? To me, this code would be better served using `map` with a single return point.

Comment: @DanielFath see my edit

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Is there any way to return from a function from inside a closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52027634/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: You should also read [How do you define custom `Error` types in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42584368/155423), which discusses how to make `?` automatically wrap underlying errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your edited example, I've created an [approximate example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9c0efade1c4875d50b577da9919595ef):

```rust
// ...
    .and_then(|b| b.into_rows().ok_or(TechnicalServerError::SERVER_RETRY))
    .and_then(|mut c| {
        if let Some(row) = c.pop() {
            User::try_from_row(row).map_err(|e| {
                error!("{:?}", e);
                TechnicalServerError::SERVER_INVALID
            })
        } else {
            return Ok(Login::Other(LoginResult::UNKNOWN_USER))
        }
    }).and_then(|u| {
        // 'u' should be of type 'user' at this point
        // some user code here...
```

I think there is a basic misunderstanding about what `and_then` does.

- `and_then` takes a `Result<T, E>`, and a function that converts `T` into `Result<U, E>` (i.e. `FnOnce(T) -> Result<U, E>`. Use this when you want to manipulate both the `Ok(val)` and the `Error`, for example you want to change remap the error and do some value processing.
- `map` takes a `Result<T, E>` and a function that converts `T` into another value `U` (i.e. `FnOnce(T) -> U`). Use this when you want to change `Ok(val)` without influencing the `Error` part.

You say you want to change the user, and that's possible like this:

```rust
db_session
    .query_with_values(true)
    .map_err(|e| {
        println!("{:?}", e);
        MyError::ServerRetry
    })
    .and_then(|f| f.get_body(true).map_err(|e2|{
        println!("{:?}", e2);
        MyError::ServerRetry
    }))
    .and_then(|b| b.into_rows(true).ok_or(MyError::ServerRetry))
    .and_then(|mut c|{
        if let Some(row) = c.pop() {
            User::from_row(row).map_err(|e3| {
                println!("{:?}", e3);
                MyError::ServerRetry
            })
        } else {
            return Ok(User{ name: "X".to_string()})
        }
    })
    .map(|mut user| {
        user.name = "CHANGED".to_string();
        user
    });
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a052f26ea68a6ae1c8a1e9b10744d256).

However, as you can see the value of query will always be `Result<User, Error>` the only way to operate on the value directly is to `unwrap` but that panics if it encounters an error. Alternatively you can use `if let` to get the value without panicking.

Answer (score 1):

Not a clean one. How about breaking out to `?` instead?

```
fn s(r: Result<Good, ()>) -> Result<Food, ()> {
    let p = match r? {
        // Should be called in the next and_then block
        Good::Ok => Pizza::Tomato,
        // Should be called in the next and_then block
        Good::Good => Pizza::Pineapple,
        Good::VeryGood => {
            return Ok(Food::Burger(Burger::Cow));
        },
    };

    Ok(Food::Pizza(p))
}
```

Comment: That would work indeed in the code I provided :) However, in my 'real' code, I have more and_then's and they are mapping types and errors, this way wouldn't be sufficient sadly :( Thanks for the answer anyway, I will update my question to make it more clear

Comment: @J.Doe: Can you create a more realistic example/show the true code, then? You can’t use `return` like that, so any alternative will probably need more context. (Also, is this targeting stable Rust or are `#![feature]`s okay?)

Comment: Well to make it simple, I am chaining multiple and_then's and sometimes, I just want to say (inside a and_then block): ok, just return this value to the caller if something is true, else just call the next and_then. This is stable rust. To wrap it up: a return statement inside a and_then block will not actually return the function but maps the given type to the returning value, making it available in the next and_then block?

Comment: @J.Doe: `return` returns from the closure being passed as an argument to `and_then`, yeah.

Comment: @J.Doe could you change example to have multiple `and_then`?